# Turn Off Deferred Segment Creation for Oracle IMPDP

Tags: oracle11g, impdp

I have a program that is calling Oracle's **impdp** utility to import a schema.  I encounter the following errors:

```
ORA-14223: Deferred segment creation is not supported for this table
```

The tables that are failing have a column of **VARRAY**.

How could I turn force the creation of segments when running the impdp utility?

Comment: What is your `impdp` command - do you have any `transform` settings, particularly `segment_creation`? Are the tables being created by the import or do they already exist in the target schema?

Comment: What schema and tablespace are you importing it into?  Deferred segment creation is [not supported](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_7002.htm#SQLRF54480) in SYS, SYSTEM, PUBLIC, OUTLN, XDB, or the SYSTEM tablespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to this problem shortly after the question was posted. The solution to this problem is to create tables that have VARRAY columns with the SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE clause.

More details are available here: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/segment-creation-on-demand-11gr2.php